# How to store data in memory

Tags: vb.net

I am reading data from wordpad one by one which records the sale of grocery item by barcode. I want to store it in memory so that after reading the whole file I can calculate the total number of the same items sold by comparing the bar code.

Answer (score 1):

Memory.  There are several types of memory.

Any variable is  a type of memory storage so one answer could be

`dim s as string = "hi"`

You can also use files as "memory"

Take a look at [this](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets8p4.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should make a class to store your items, then use a `List(Of T)` to hold instances of the class.

Comment: iam new with vb.net and a bit of explaination would be a great help..